# 'Run-time error 13' for a dynamic range with variables in VBA. Data type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am receiving a 'runtime error 13' for a line that is supposed to select a dynamic range from a worksheet in a opened workbook. I commented the line in the program.

From research, I found that the 13 error is caused by a mismatch in data, so I tried changing my "v1, v2, v3..." variables to integers(they were `Dim As Long`).This had no effect.

I specify a workbook and worksheet for each cell and range because I was receiving a '1004 error' before, & the answer from another thread was to qualify the `ranges()` & `cells()`.

What is causing this error? Could there be an issue with the workbook and worksheet datatypes? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub FillPartNumRev()
Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
Dim v1 As Range, v2 As Range, v3 As Range
Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long, r3 As Long, r4 As Long, r5 As Long
Dim c1 As Long, c2 As Long, c3 As Long, c4 As Long, c5 As Long
For x = 1 To 5000

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="IPIC_DATA.xlsx")

r1 = 7: c1 = 0
r2 = 7: c2 = 1
r3 = 7: c3 = 2
r4 = 7: c4 = 0
r5 = 7: c5 = 1


Set v1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r1, c1), wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r2, c2))
'run-time error 13
Set v2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r3, c3))
Set v3 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r1, c1))
Set v4 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r4, c4), wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r5, c5))

    If v4 <> "" & v2 = "" Then
        v1.Copy v4

    ElseIf v4 = "" Then
        r1 = r1 + 7
        r2 = r2 + 7

    End If

r4 = r4 + 1
c4 = c4 + 1
r5 = r5 + 1
c5 = c5 + 1
r3 = r3 + 1
c3 = c3 + 1


Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: Put them back as Long.

Comment: Do you really want to open IPIC_DATA.xlsx 5000 times?

Comment: It still gave me the same error after I put them back as Long.

Comment: No I don't want to open it that many times. Should I put the 'Set wb =....' before the For loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kudos to @Jeeped for sorting this out - however a *type mismatch* error is very common when working with Excel cells in VBA. This answer addresses the more common cause, **for which your now-working code still isn't immune to**.

---

A *type mismatch* error is typically something you get when you assign a cell's value to some typed variable, be it a `String`, a `Double`, a `Date`, or whatever - like this:

```
Dim v As String
v = sheet.Range("A1").Value
```

It can also happen when a cell's value is involved in an expression, like this:

```
If sheet.Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
```

Why is that?

If the cell is empty, or *actually* contains a usable value, there's no problem. However if the cell contains an `Error` value, such as `#N/A`, `#VALUE!`, or any other cell error, then the above code throws run-time error 13 as you're experiencing.

A cell's value is a `Variant`; a `Variant` can contain anything, including a `String`, an `Object` reference, or an `Error` value. VBA will implicitly convert a `Variant/Date` to a `Variant/String` if you're reading a cell value into some `String` variable, or if you're comparing it to some string literal.

But a `Variant/Error` can't be implicitly (or explicitly) converted to anything.

So the morale of the story, is that you can never assume what the `Variant` subtype of a cell is going to be, nor that this subtype can be coerced into a specific data type.

To avoid *type mismatch* errors when working with cells, you need to read the cell values into a `Variant`:

```
Dim v As Variant
v = sheet.Range("A1").Value
```

And then use the `IsError` function to determine whether you're looking at a `Variant/Error`:

```
If Not IsError(v) Then
    'v is safe to convert to whatever you need it to be
Else
    'cell contains an error value
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Put `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="IPIC_DATA.xlsx")` above and outside the loop. You are trying to open it 5000 times.
2. `Workbooks(wb)` should be `wb`. You've set the workbook object to a workbook type var. No need to use the object to identify wb out of the workbooks collection.
3. Go back to Long. Integers aren't cool.

Here are some corrected range and cell references.

```
'I made a guess as to the folder location of IPIC_DATA.xlsx
'don't rely on default folder locations; be as specific as possible
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=thisworkbook.path & "\IPIC_DATA.xlsx")

For x = 1 To 5000

    r1 = 7: c1 = 0  'there is no column 0
    r2 = 7: c2 = 1
    r3 = 7: c3 = 2
    r4 = 7: c4 = 0 'there is no column 0
    r5 = 7: c5 = 1

    with wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set v1 = .Range(.Cells(r1, c1), .Cells(r2, c2))
        Set v2 = .Cells(r3, c3)
        Set v3 = .Cells(r1, c1)
        Set v4 = .Range(.Cells(r4, c4), .Cells(r5, c5))
    end with

    '...
Next x
```

Comment: Went back to Long & wb, but it gave me a 1004 error again. Is the path to the range not being specified correctly?

Comment: I corrected my range and cell references, but am still receiving the same error. Does this mean that the .Range is unable to find the cells I am specifying with my variables?

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice until I got your range references cleaned up but C1 and C4 cannot be zero; there is no column 0. Perhaps you intended to use them as a progressive offset but they cannot be used directly as a column index number when they are zero.

Comment: Also, the workbook was able to be opened before so I didn't changed the filename.

Comment: Yes, you were relying on the default folder and it worked last time. It may not work next time if the default folder location changes.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped. I added 1 to all of my range references because I had originally started at 0,1,2..etc. & now it can find those ranges.